# How to remove the tick from a tkinter checkbox

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox

There are two checkboxes. When one is ticked I need the other to remove it's tick, supposed it is ticked. How do I do that?

I've tried disabling and enabling the checkboxes with a delay but they return to their initial condition (if it was ticked, it remains ticked).

```py
from tkinter import *


def removetickwoman():
    # something to remove the tick from woman


def removetickman():
    # something to remove the tick from man


root = Tk()
chkvar1 = IntVar()
chkvar2 = IntVar()


check1 = Checkbutton(root, text="man", variable=chkvar1, command=removetickwoman)
check1.pack()
check2 = Checkbutton(root, text="woman", variable=chkvar2, command=removetickman)
check2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is not only possible, but already proposed by `tkinter`: you need to use a `RadioButton` instead of a `CheckButton`:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()    

MODES = [("Man", "M"), ("Woman", "W")]
v = tk.StringVar()
v.set("M")

for text, mode in MODES:
    b = tk.Radiobutton(root, text=text,
                    variable=v, value=mode)
    b.pack(anchor=tk.W)

root.mainloop()
```